# How can I add multiple build paths for my jar file?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, minecraft-fabric

I want to have my jar file not only in my build/libs folder, but also somewhere else on my system. On maven, I just needed to copy and paste the entire  section in my pom.xml and change the directory from there. Is there something similar in gradle?

This is how I am building my projects:
[image: Build Task]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open your Project Structure (right-click on your project directory in IntelliJ, and select open module settings) -> Artifacts -> Here you can change you're jar-output directory
[image]

...and also add new jar output directories

To change your out-directory path select Project Structure -> Modules -> Paths, and change output path
[image]

Comment: So I tried this and rebuilt my original jar. Nothing changed, its still building in the old location and not building in the new location.

Comment: Oh, I think I understood it wrong, if you want to change the path of  you're out directory, you can do this at Project settings -> project, there should be something like "output directory"

Comment: There is no output directory in project settings -> project

Comment: You're right I wasn't in front of my PC when I wrote this, it is actually in Project Settings -> Modules -> Paths

Comment: This is tough. It's not building it in the directory I set. Perhaps it has something to do with how I am building it? I am double clicking the build task in the gradle tab.

Comment: can you please add screens of the configuration in Project Settings?

Comment: I added it to my main post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245195/discussion-between-sebastian-and-zoboo).